# Mac OS X, Apache, block external access

Tags: macos, apache, security, localhost

I have set up the pre installed apache server that comes with Mac OS X 10.8 for local testing.

I want to ensure it is completely blocked off to the outside world. The only change I have made is in the httpd.conf file and detailed that below. Is this enough or are there other settings I can amend to ensure my local server is safe from the outside world?

From this:

```
Listen :80
```

To this:

```
Listen localhost:80
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you listen on the local "loopback" IP address, only traffic from the same local network can access it, since traffic on that subnet isn't routed. However, you should not use the hostname `localhost` in your config because that hostname lookup can be attacked.

For example, if someone modified your `/etc/hosts` file and and put in a different IP address for `localhost` then restarted your web server, it would be listening on the new IP address.

Instead, enter the actual loopback IP(v4) address:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: Thanks, is this the only setting I need to change to ensure my local server is off limits to the outside world?